# How to cast from Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement to System.Windows.Controls.UIElement

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime

I'm trying to create a new UI for an app I developed for the Windows Store using the Windows Runtime API. This new client is going to be a WPF Desktop App. I'm trying to reuse as much code as I can but I'm facing several issues.

Fortunately there's a way to use WinRT in a WPF Desktop app (see [this](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-winrt-apis-from-desktop-applications) and [this](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToCallWinRTAPIsInWindows8FromCDesktopApplicationsWinRTDiagram.aspx))

Now I'm blocked by the following issue: 
The [MediaCapture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.aspx) class has a method to start the preview of a device, after I've started the preview I can create a [CaptureElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.captureelement) to display the preview.
CaptureElement is part of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls and cannot be used in containers from System.Windows.Controls in which the WPF UI is built.

Am I going anywhere with this approach? what would you recommend? How can I display the preview of a device in the WPF app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`CaptureElement` can't be used in desktop applications - the documentation says "[Windows Store apps only]". In general - the UI controls from WPF and WinRT/XAML can't be used outside of their respective domains (desktop/immersive UI). In a WPF app you need to use WPF controls - e.g. DirectShow for camera capture,

Comment: Although 5 years on - it might actually be becoming possible to have UWP controls (islands) in a WPF app... See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls